# HTML Tools: Ways to get the width and height of a desired div?

Tags: html

If I want to make a div class in a CSS file which is simply a rectangular box on a page. how can I calculate the height and width of this div without excessive trial and error?

Really all I need is a simple tool which you can click on one section of the screen, and then click on another section of the screen and it gives you the horizontal, vertical, and diagonal  pixel distance between the 2 clicked points.  Does anyone know of a tool to do this?  Perhaps I can create one, this seems very useful.

Comment: With JavaScript, or a library thereof.

Comment: [**What type of question should I ask on SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Use PureJS or [VaporJS](http://vaporjs.com/)

Comment: Ghillied, I have read the rules at least three times... I feel like the questions I ask on SO at least follow the majority of those guidelines, but I'll be happy to take this down if necessary.  Quite sorry if that is the case.  (But isn't this a fairly specific question?  I couldn't find a tool like this on Google, so I figured I would ask on here.)

Comment: It's too vague. What have you tried? Perhaps put some code in there. Otherwise it's like asking your personal army to to do job for you.
There are ways to get the cursor click position.

Comment: And maybe the OP doesn't know any of those methods and is asking for some? @Ghillied

Comment: @MisterMelancholy If someone does not *know* how to use something, there are plenty of tutorials **everywhere** on the web. From the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about): *Don't ask about...

Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for **(show your work!)** //
Product or service recommendations or comparisons*

Comment: OP wasn't asking how to use a specific tool, they were asking for the name of a tool that they could use to accomplish their task. Granted, this question is a better fit for something like [Super User](http://superuser.com/), but OP was not trying to get us to do his work for him. @Ghillied

Comment: Ghillied, i see where you are coming from there.  But I did honestly make an effort to search on Google (not just a quick glance at the first page, but clicking on many results from different searches on page 1 and 2).  Next time I will attempt to search and think about the problem more in depth before asking on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screenshot > Open in [GIMP](http://gimp.org) or something similar > count pixels.

However, if you want actual developer tools, it depends on the browser:

- Firefox has [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) (add-on). To find it with Firebug, look in the HTML view, right-click your element, click "Inspect in DOM", and find "innerWidth/innerHright".
- Chrome has [Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements) (extension). I believe this shows you height/width just by hovering over the Element in HTML view.
- Opera has something built-in called [DragonFly](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-to-opera-dragonfly/). Select your Element in HTML view, and in the right window select "Layout" and look at the "clientWidth/clientHight".

I don't believe there's a way to find either with Internet Explorer or Safari though.

Comment: This is also a great idea to use Gimp (or Photoshop), can't believe I didn't think of this myself.  And Firebug rocks!

Comment: I do it at work all the time. Very handy. Also, if my answer worked for you, please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

regarding the first part: you can tweak around with your div in chrome developer tools- very convenient.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements

regarding the second part: you can write a function than handles the mouseclick events and calculates the number you want based on the coordinates. this function can then be used as a snippet in chrome dev tools.
I will try to write one for you in a few minutes...

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for everyone's helpful comments.  Feel free to post that program you are writing if you'd like, although (if you're busy) it looks like the chrome developer tools might be exactly what I needed.

Comment: glad you like the tools. If this suits your needs then I will skip adding the mouseclick function. I highly recommend reading the docs for chrome developer tools, you will discover many surprisingly convenient features there.